# Flutter Drawer Animation Behavior

Tags: flutter

I can see that flutter's navbar default animation is from left to right  but somehow in my app the default is bottom to up. here's navbar code.

```
import 'package:flutter_svg/flutter_svg.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';

import 'package:frontend/src/providers/auth.provider.dart';
import 'package:frontend/src/services/auth_service.dart';

class Navbar extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _NavbarState createState() => _NavbarState();
}

class _NavbarState extends State<Navbar> {
  String nombres = '';

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    Future.delayed(Duration.zero, () {
      getDatosCliente();
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      color: Colors.white,
      width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
      child: Drawer(
        
        child: ListView(
          children: [/*menu items*/]
 
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

 

 
  List<Widget> _itemMenuFunction(
      String texto, IconData icon, void Function()? onTap) {
    return [
      ListTile(
        contentPadding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
          horizontal: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.025,
        ),
        leading: Icon(
          icon,
          color: Color.fromRGBO(80, 80, 80, 1),
          size: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.037,
        ),
        title: Text(
          texto,
          style: TextStyle(
            fontSize: 20,
            color: Color.fromRGBO(123, 123, 123, 1),
          ),
        ),
        onTap: onTap,
      ),
      SizedBox(
        height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.025,
      ),
    ];
  }
}
```

[This is the result not what i'm specting, to be clear im not specifing this behabior anywhere, and somehow I suspect some other widget is overriding this behavior.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OLlGR.gif)

Thank U very much.

and this is how i call it from other pages

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    Size size = MediaQuery.of(context).size;
    return Scaffold(
      extendBodyBehindAppBar: true,
      drawer: Navbar(),
      body: BackgroundWhite(/*inside body code*/)
 
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you try removing the root widget `Container()` and have `Drawer()` as the root widget in `NavBar()`?

The reason being that **drawer** attribute in `Scaffold()` could be expecting `Drawer()` object which would handle default animations of drawer behaviour.

Comment: Yes I tried that one, but no changes. I took it out and the animation keeps the same.

Comment: can you try by not using extendBodyBehindAppBar and see if that works? @Ricardo

Comment: I tried That too. I just discovered the reason for this bahavior was that i wasn't using the appbar default menu's button. i was using another one because of the app design. The solution is to change the design to use the app bar.

Answer (score 0):

I just discovered the reason for this behaviour: I wasn't using the app bar default menu button. Instead, I was using another one because of the app design. The solution is to change the design to use the app bar. After this it goes from left to right as expected.

```
      appBar: AppBar(title: Text('test')),
      drawer: Navbar(),
      body: BackgroundWhite(
        child: SingleChildScrollView(
          child: Column(
            children: [
              MenuLogoBar(size: size) /*this was the original menu buttton*/
            ],
      )))
```